# PyTorch ROCm is out - How to select Radeon GPU as device

Tags: pytorch

since Pytorch released the ROCm version, which enables me to use other gpus than nvidias, how can I select my radeon gpu as device in python?
Obviously, code like device = torch.cuda.is_available or device = torch.device("cuda") is not working. Thanks for any help. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This took me forever to figure out. I'm still having some configuration issues with my AMD GPU, so I haven't been able to test that this works, but, according to this github pytorch thread, the Rocm integration is written so you *can* just call torch.device('cuda') and no actual porting is required!

See the thread here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/10670

Comment: yes that might work. My conclusion was that I saw that my GPU was not explicitly supported. For further readers: I opened as well a github issue in the pytorch repo and they replied, that torch.device('cuda') will work. See more here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/55223

Comment: Yes, that might be as the list of supported GPUs is quite small. I believe my answer is the correct answer to the question, however. Mind selecting it as the correct answer?