# Set Pytorch to run on AMD GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, amd-gpu, amd-rocm

According to the official docs, now PyTorch supports AMD GPUs. ROCm 4.2 can be installed through pip. But I can not find in Google nor the official docs how to force my DL training to use the GPU. What is the AMD equivalent to the following command?

```py
torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

Comment: Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66909581/pytorch-rocm-is-out-how-to-select-radeon-gpu-as-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROCm translates CUDA codes. So `torch.cuda.is_available()` should work.